# Issue with log4j.properties on the command propmt

Tags: java, batch-file, logging, parameters

I'm trying to create a batch file for Windows (*.bat) for executing a Java application. I've set up everything but the logger. I have made the call to  `BasicConfigurator.configure()` and put the file `log4j.properties` on the root of the project which works fine in the IDE (Eclipse) but when I try to do the same through a batch file, it doesn't work.

I've already tried to move the file to other path but it didn't work and I don't know what else to try.

eInvoice.bat (CLASSPATH is suppose to be defined previously)

```
java -Xmx500m -cp %CLASSPATH% com.mycompany.einvoice.InvoiceSender -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties
```

log4j.properties

```
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=INFO, file 

# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=AplFacturae.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is useful for someone, but I found the source of the problem and It was related with the order of the parameters. The main class has to be the last parameter unless it has parameters. So I just swapped the last two parametes and it started to work

```
java -Xmx500m -cp %CLASSPATH% -Dlog4j.configuration=log4j.properties com.mycompany.einvoice.InvoiceSender
```

In the moment I fix the problem I realized the reason. The main class can have paramentes, so, every parameter I use before of the main class, belongs to the main class instead of Java.

```
public static void main (String[] args){
   ...
}
```